# Underscore-cli on Mac with NVM & Error: Cannot find module

Tags: macos, module, npm, nvm

I recently installed underscore-cli to my Mac (OS X Mavericks) and it's working but special commands (like map, filter) are writing errors to stderr. Propably some kind of installation hiccup with NVM/Node/NPM/underscore-cli.

I installed underscore-cli with

```
$ npm install -g underscore-cli
```

An example run:

```
dyn-foo touko:~$ underscore map --data '[1, 2, 3, 4]' 'value+1'
[2, 3, 4, 5]
dyn-foo touko:~$ 
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/touko/.nvm/v0.10.19/bin/underscore-map'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

Tried also to fetch latest 0.10 with nvm (-> Node 0.10.26, npm 1.4.3) but same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue today. 
here's a work around and the discussion about it:
https://github.com/ddopson/underscore-cli/pull/29

Briefly:

```
npm remove underscore-cli -g
npm install -g commander@1.0.5 underscore-cli
```

this should be a temporary solution so keep an eye on updated versions.